# Get the status of the current task

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

When I mention task below, I am referring to a specific Android concept here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes

Hi there,
Let's say there is a button in a base activity. When this button is pressed, a third party file viewer activity is launched from base activity through intent, which displays a file to the user. We do not set any flag in this intent, so I assume the viewer activity is in the same task as the base activity.

So when this viewer activity is in the foreground, is there anyway to detect Home button press, since this triggers the status of the current task to change (probably from having one activity in the foreground to having all of them in the background?)?

Any thought/idea/comment is highly welcomed!

Thanks!

Comment: You say "We do not set any flag in this intent, so I assume the viewer activity is in the same task as the base activity". This may or may not be true. If the viewer activity has a special `launchMode` the viewer may end up in another task even if you don't set any Intent flags when launching it.

Comment: Also, please explain what you are trying to do. Your question doesn't really indicate what information you need and why you need it. If you explain what it is you are trying to accomplish maybe we can suggest and easier/better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code at least get the name of the current top activity:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
  if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
    topActivityName = tasks.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
  }
```